# Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [PreviewFilter]: could not be initialized

Tags: websphere, websphere-portal

This issue happens when I try to access to login page of our web service which hosted on IBM websphere application server 8.5.

I get the following error on the browser:
Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [PreviewFilter]: could not be initialized

I checked the log, and find out that PreviewFilter could not be initialized because JNDI lookup for UserRegistry is failed.

Here is the log:

```
 [8/12/22 16:27:56:217 EDT] 00000198 PreviewFilter E com.ibm.wps.services.preview.PreviewFilterImpl init(arg0) EJPSD0028E: The filter com.ibm.wps.services.preview.PreviewFilterImpl could not be initialized due to error: Context: ib2c_cell02/clusters/ib2c_Cluster, name: UserRegistry: First component in name UserRegistry not found.
                                     javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Context: ib2c_cell02/clusters/ib2c_Cluster, name: UserRegistry: First component in name UserRegistry not found. [Root exception is org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0]
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.mapNotFoundException(CNContextImpl.java:4565)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1823)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1778)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.lookupExt(CNContextImpl.java:1435)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.lookup(CNContextImpl.java:617)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:165)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:179)
        at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.lookup(DelegateContext.java:161)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:423)
        at com.ibm.wps.services.preview.PreviewFilterImpl$DefaultDependenciesImpl.<init>(PreviewFilterImpl.java:182)
        at com.ibm.wps.services.preview.PreviewFilterImpl$DefaultDependenciesImpl.<init>(PreviewFilterImpl.java:175)
        at com.ibm.wps.services.preview.PreviewFilterImpl.init(PreviewFilterImpl.java:264)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.init(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:145)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager._loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:607)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:514)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterInstanceWrapper(WebAppFilterManager.java:319)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterChain(WebAppFilterManager.java:392)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:931)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:952)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:213)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:287)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:558)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:608)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:985)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1074)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
    Caused by: org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipcos.WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.do_resolve_complete_info(WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.java:590)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.cosbase.WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.resolve_complete_info(WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.java:2216)
        at com.ibm.WsnOptimizedNaming._NamingContextStub.resolve_complete_info(_NamingContextStub.java:538)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl$2.run(CNContextImpl.java:2959)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl$2.run(CNContextImpl.java:2955)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.CommonHelpers.retry(CommonHelpers.java:871)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.cosResolve(CNContextImpl.java:2953)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1819)
        ... 32 more
```

I try to clean up the temp and wstemp folder under WAS profile root folder, and restart the server, but it does not work. Does anyone have any suggestions on this issue?